# Merging and managing multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript, modularity

We have a platform where we run different types of applications for clients with different functionality. For all intents and purposes these applications are completely independent from each other.

This puts us in the curious situation where type A,B needs JavaScript for voting, application A,C needs JavaScript for dealing with media. Right now this is split up in different JavaScript files like:

```
/application A
  /common.js
/application B
  /common.js
```

This is a bit of an issue when you want to patch something and you have to go in and edit all of our JavaScript. Now we could take all of our platform javascript and bundle it into one giant pile, but since users will usually only ever see one of these applications it seems like a waste and that it won't scale very well.

I think I would rather have something like:

```
/Applications
    core.js
voting.js
media.js
social-media.js
```

Which would get merged by a build script. Now the naive method I would employ would be to make each feature into a jQuery plugin and then merge them when pushing to production before minification, but I'd be interested in better approaches for modularizing JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There are many Javascript module systems out there. For example, [requireJs](http://requirejs.org/) allows you to manage dependencies dinamically during development (by inserting extra script tags) but comes with a build system so that you can package everything together for production.